# Line Graph where each line is a column in the same table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am trying to make a line graph in Azure Data Explorer, I have a single table and I am trying to make each line in the line graph be based on a column in that table.

Using a single column works just fine with the below query

```
scandevicedata
| where SuccessFullScan == 1
| summarize SuccessFulScans = count() by scans = bin(todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc), 30s)
```

The problem is now I want to add a second column from the same table like this

```
scandevicedata
| where UnSuccessFullScan == 1
| summarize UnSuccessFulScans = count() by scans = bin(todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc), 30s)
```

As you can see the first query takes out successful scans and the second query takes out Un Successful scans and now I want to combine them in the same output and do a graph on them but I cant figure out how to do this since they are different columns

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `countif()` aggregation function :

```
scandevicedata
| summarize
       Successful = countif(SuccessFullScan == 1),
       Unsuccessful = countif(UnsuccessFullScan == 1) 
    by bin(todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc), 30s)
| render timechart
```